# Reading external txt file and making it into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to load an external file with list of IDs and the corresponding name. The code below seems to work but I need them in a separate file and I'm not sure how to make them into an object. The "i" variable is something i take from the query string and i already got that down.

```
var dict = { 1 : "Matthew", 2 : "Andrei", 3 : "Alex" }; 
var name='Dear '+ dict[i]+','; 
document.getElementById("name").textContent = name;
```

Comment: <script src="data.js">/*inside data.js, not the script */  var dictionary = {...};</script> , before you include your code that depends on this

Comment: @Cruiser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script you aren't supposed to have a body in a script tag with a src attribute.  Some browsers may react badly, given that it's against the standard.

Comment: I know, i was just trying to show him, with limited space, that putting his var inside the other file is all he has to do. I edited it a bit

Comment: @Martin I think the right way here would be to make the list of ids a json and store them in a  `.json` file, then use XMLHttpRequest() to get the file. then do something like this `JSON.parse(xhrResult);`

Comment: @Martin Refer this link https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

@Martin,

If you just include the dictionary in a JS file and then use a script tag to pull it down, you're good to go.

```
// ids.js
var dict = { 1 : "Matthew", 2 : "Andrei", 3 : "Alex" };
```

and

```
//index.html
<script src='/ids.js'></script>
<script>
   console.log(dict[1]); // will return "Matthew"
</script>
```